# Is there way to check if several fields from JOIN are equal?

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

E.g. :

I have query:

```
select coalesce(VV1.[TimeStamp], VV2.[TimeStamp]...) as MyDate, V1, V2, .. VN
    from VV1
    full join VV2
    full join VV3
    ...
    full outer join VVN
    on VV1.TimeStamp = VV2.TimeStamp
    and VV2.TimeStamp = VV3.TimeStamp
    ... 
    and VVN-1.TimeStamp = VVN.TimeStamp
```

I want to generate it as string but it's complex with `on` part ... So

- Is it possible to write it in better way?
- maybe somehow write `on AllOfThemAreEqual(VV1.TimeStamp, VV2.TimeStamp .. VVN.TimeStamp)` ? But I doubt if that is possible :(
- Maybe it's possible to store previous value in temp variable and then extract from there? This last option looks most real for me.

SQLFibble : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4e138/3/0

```
CREATE TABLE T1(
    [ValueId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PointId] [int] NULL,
    [Value] [int] NULL,
    [TimeStamp] [datetime] NULL
  );

INSERT INTO T1
           ([PointId]
           ,[Value]
           ,[TimeStamp])
     VALUES
           (1, 1, 1900-01-01)
INSERT INTO T1
           ([PointId]
           ,[Value]
           ,[TimeStamp])
     VALUES
           (2, 2, 1900-01-01)
;
```

and

```
WITH VV1 AS  (
            SELECT  [TimeStamp], [Value] AS V1 FROM T1
            WHERE   [PointId] = 1
        ), VV2 AS  (
            SELECT  [TimeStamp], [Value] AS V2 FROM T1
            WHERE   [PointId] = 2
        )
SELECT
  coalesce(VV1.[TimeStamp], VV2.[TimeStamp]) AS dt
  , V1, V2
FROM VV1
FULL JOIN VV2
ON VV1.TimeStamp = VV2.TimeStamp
```

Comment: The use cases of full outer joins are few and far apart in most real-world applications. An alert bell should go off in your head if you see one. Don't use them lightly.

Comment: Why the `FULL OUTER` join instead of an `INNER`?

Comment: INNER returns no data... they are not crossing, but `full join` will return same data.

Comment: "I want to generate it as string but ..." Do you want to build dynamic query?

Comment: There is an SQL Server [connect item](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/153679/natural-join-and-using-clause-in-joins) asking for natural join and USING to be added - these are both features that work based on the same column names appearing on both sides of the join which your use cases suggests is so - but it's not yet been implemented.

Comment: Maybe you can set up an example at http://sqlfiddle.com/. Without data everybody is forced to guess what you are looking at.

Comment: I provided linke to SQL Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4e138/3/0

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to achieve a dynamic pivot. Bad idea in SQL, let your presentation layer handle this. If you have a **fixed** number of items in your pivot then SQL will manage it.

Comment: The data really comes from a single table?

Comment: @gvee yes, something alike but a bit different also pivot works with only one table, isn't it? Maybe there could be better solution?

Comment: @Blam possibly not, possibly yes

Comment: By the way, in your sample query, you have to quote '1900-01-01', otherwise it's the date ('1905-03-14') which corresponds to the integer of 1898 (which is 1900 minus 1 minus 1) converted to a date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4e138/3/0

Here's a different approach. No need for extra joins, just gives you one row per `Timestamp`.

```
SELECT "Timestamp"
     , Max(CASE WHEN PointId = 1 THEN "Value" END) As V1
     , Max(CASE WHEN PointId = 2 THEN "Value" END) As V2
     , Max(CASE WHEN PointId = 3 THEN "Value" END) As V3
     , Max(CASE WHEN PointId = 4 THEN "Value" END) As V4
     , Max(CASE WHEN PointId = 5 THEN "Value" END) As V5
FROM   t1
GROUP
    BY "Timestamp"
```

Please try to avoid dynamic SQL wherever possible

Comment: To be honest it still being wrong since it will cause troubles when there are more than one table :)

Comment: @Heather your original question does not state this fact, therefore the solution provided does not cater for this. It would appear that you are abusing dynamic SQL which is, more often than not, a sign of a flaw in your design/solution. Perhaps you need to go back to the drawing board?

Comment: I've managed to get it done :) in complex way with full join but it works as I wanted it to.